# Using Jira as Board and Azure Devops as CI/CD

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, jira, continuous-deployment, jira-agile

Have you ever tried to use Jira as development board and Azure DevOps as repository + CI/CD Pipelines?
I was wondering if it is possible to link to Jira tasks the results of Azure pipelines deployments and builds, i found [this plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1224155/azure-devops-integration-for-jira?tab=overview&hosting=cloud) but reviews say is not working properly recently.

**EDIT**

Using the mentioned plugins seems the right way although they are not working properly at the moment. I will try to contact the support as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you can try to use the [plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1220515/azure-pipelines-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) for Azure DevOps.

Then you can use the flow: Jira -> GitHub -> Azure Pipelines CI -> Azure Pipelines CD.

For more information, you could refer to the [Azure Pipelines integration with Jira Software](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-jira/blob/master/tutorial.md).

Comment: Unfortunately reviews for this plugin say it doesn't work properly anymore, like the plugin i linked... It looks like microsoft dropped support

Comment: I think you can try to submit a suggestion ticket here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest